# Problema criando um data.frame

Tags: r

Estou querendo exportar vários resultados para o excel e para isso preciso antes deixa-los no formato ideal, porém estou enfrentando problemas pois quero eles ficam empilhados numa única coluna.
Esse é um exemplo para mostrar o que eu quero que seja feito.

```
x=c(1,2,3)
x1=c("um","dois","tres")
d1=as.data.frame(x,x1)

z=1000
z1=c("média")
d2=as.data.frame(z,z1)

y=10
y1=c("taxa")
d3=as.data.frame(y,y1)

exportar=as.data.frame(list(d1,d2,d3))
```

A saída que tenho é essa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém desse jeito, omite o nome das linhas de "z" e "y" e triplica alguns resultados. Eu quero que a saída seja na primeira coluna os nomes das linhas das variáveis e na segunda coluna os valores um embaixo do outro.

Eu quero na primeiro coluna:
*um

dois

tres

média

taxa*
e na segunda:
*1

2

3

1000

10*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como no seu exemplo você possui as variáveis que irão construir os `data.frame`, de uma forma bem genérica você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
data.frame(c(x,z,y), row.names = c(x1, z1, y1))
```

Porém, acho mais esperto você indicar as variáveis indexadas de cada `data.frame` nessa construção:

```
data.frame(c(d1$x,d2$z,d3$y), row.names = c(row.names(d1),row.names(d2),row.names(d3)))
```